# DOs and DONTs for Indexes

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design, indexing

What are some DOs and DONTs for improving database performance using index?

A DO would be a case in which an index should be created, or another indexes related tip that will improve performance.

A DONT will be a case when an index shouldn't be created, or another index related action that can hurt the performance.

Comment: the question is waaaaay too broad.

Comment: @Spudley how? Its specific about mysql indexes, how much more specific should it be?

Comment: From the close reason: "overly broad".  It is a question that invites vast, most likely subjective lists, those are generally frowned upon.

Comment: @Orbling I don't see how, I'm asking what are some DOs for indexes that would improve database performance and DONTs that will be harmful, I don't see how there can be any subjective answers for that. I will edit the question and clarify it.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a good candidate for a wiki question, and that it should be re-opened.

Comment: @Click Upvote: The problem is that what helps and hinders varies very much under the use of the database in question.  The mix of queries in play, the frequency of modifications versus plain reads.  The complexity of the queries, the way in which they are joined, restricted and ordered.  The choices with indexes could fill a large book and has, many times.

Comment: @Denis: If it were a straight forward list question, applicable to all situations, I would agree, it is however predominantly specific to individual situations, so would not be of general use.

Comment: @Orbling I'm sure there are many general tips which work/don't work in 80% of the situations, and I'd like to know them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Generally speaking:

#### 1. Don't add an index unless you actually need it.

Each index makes writes slower...

#### 2. An index will be used on where clauses:

```
-- index on foo (bar)
select bar from foo where bar = :bar;
```

By the same token it'll be used in foreign key references (on both tables).

```
-- index on foo (bar) if baz (bar) is frequently updated/deleted.
create table foo (bar references baz (bar));
```

#### 3. An index will be used for sorting, especially when tied to a limit:

```
-- index on foo (bar)
select bar from foo order by bar limit 10;
```

#### 4. Multicolumn indexes are occasionally useful when 2. and 3. both apply.

In this case put the where conditions first, and the sort key last:

```
-- index on foo (baz, bar)
select bar from foo where baz between :baz1 and :baz2 group by bar;
```

#### 5. Keep your table statistics up to date.

If the table stats are garbage, there is little chances that the optimizer will use your indexes. Manually vacuum/analyze your database if needed.

#### 6. Index usage depends on your table repartition.

Past a certain threshold of rows retrieved, it'll be faster to do a full table scan. If your index is on a boolean field that more or less splits your table in two, it'll never be used.

Likewise, if your data is stored in such a way that the index scan will likely end up randomly accessing nearly ever applicable disk page for that table, the planner will prefer a full table scan.

#### 7. Consider partial/expression indexes when available.

If you've a field that has the same value except for 10% of your rows, consider a partial index on it (i.e. where not that value). This results in a much smaller index without hindering its actual usefulness.

If you're constantly querying against an expression applied to your column and you platform offers expression indexes, consider adding an index on it. When used, the expression won't get evaluated for each row.

Comment: With MySQL you do have to be a bit careful with multi-column indexes.  They handle differently with range queries to equality.

Answer (score 11):

1. Measure system throughput as a whole.  An index may help some queries but harm insert, update and delete.
2. Create the index.
3. Measure system throughput as a whole.

If performance is better, leave the index there.  If performance is worse, delete it.