# SQLite queries running slowly, need optimization help

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, optimization

I have a SQLite DB with about 24k records in one of the tables, 15 in the other. The table with 15 records holds information about forms that need to be completed by users (roughly 1k users). The table with 24k records holds information about which forms have been completed by who, and when. When a user logs in, there is about a ~3/4 second wait time while the queries run to determine what the user has finished so far. Too long for my client. I know I can't be doing my queries in the best way, because they are contained within a loop. But I cannot seem to figure out how to optimize my query.

The queries run as follows:

1) Select all of the forms and information

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_forms");
while($row = $result->fetchArray()){
//Run other query 2 here
}
```

2) For each form/row, run a query that figures out what is the most recent completion information about that form for the user.

```
$complete = $db->querySingle("SELECT * FROM tbl_completion AS forms1 
      WHERE userid='{$_SESSION['userid']}' AND form_id='{$row['id']}' AND forms1.id IN 
      (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_completion 
      GROUP BY tbl_completion.userid, tbl_completion.form_id)", true);
```

There are 15 forms, so there is a total of 16 queries running. However, with my table structure, I'm unsure as how to get the "most recent" (aka max form id) form information using 1 joined query instead.

My table structure looks like so:

```
tbl_forms:
id | form_name | deadline | required | type | quicklink

tbl_completion:
id | userid | form_id | form_completion | form_path | timestamp | accept | reject
```

Edit: `Index on tbl_forms (id), Index on tbl_forms (id, form_name), Index on tbl_complete (id)`

I've tried using a query that is like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_completion AS forms1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_forms ON forms1.form_id = tbl_forms.id 
WHERE forms1.userid='testuser' AND forms1.id IN 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_completion GROUP BY tbl_completion.userid, tbl_completion.form_id)
```

Which will give me the most up-to-date information about the forms completed, as well as the form information, but the only problem with this is I need to output all the forms in a table (like: Form 1-Incomplete, Form 2-Completed, etc) I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work with the left table being tbl_forms and getting all form info, as well as "latest" form tbl_completion info. I also tried doing a 3 LOJ with the last "table" as a temp table holding the maxid, but it was very slow AND didn't give me what I wanted.

Can anybody help?? Is there a better optimized query I can run once, or can I do something else on the DB side to speed this up? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i don't see any information here about how your tables are indexed ... that would be necessary to start troubleshooting.

Comment: @Don Dickinson: which would be the best way to show this, creation statement?

Comment: How about "index on 'xxx', index on 'xxx,xxx2'"? :) Try to run an EXPLAIN on the 2nd query aswell (as that one's probably the bad one).

Comment: Do you think breaking the database into smaller-size databases is possible with your system?

Comment: @Fge: added info about indices- which are probably not at all as useful as they could be. I'm trying to do an EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN also. Thanks for the suggestions, btw

Comment: @BeingSimpler - At this point, probably not. It may be possible in the future when we hit a "lull" - sometime in the next few months the system will no longer be used and edits to the system will be made for next time but not atm.

Comment: @BeingSimpler: that is definitely not the right approach. 24k records is tiny. I'm guessing a lack of appropriate indexes, plus sub-optimal query is the issue here.

Comment: @Richard: hmm... have you got any solution for this?
@Charx: good, just wonder if the table contains 240k records one day :)

Comment: @BeingSimpler: Not likely. (Well- maybe not. Don't want to make assumptions). The database will be purged every year this event occurs, and most of the action has already happened.

Comment: @Charx: let's wait for the solution then, I'm not too good at database :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing indexes. See:

[DOs and DONTs for Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes)

Also, the `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_completion GROUP BY tbl_completion.userid, tbl_completion.form_id` could presumably discard unneeded rows if you toss in your userid in a where clause.

Comment: I'd suggest both. :-) See the post on index dos/donts, it'll make more sense why.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be running into the concurrency limitations of SQLite.  SQLite does not support concurrent writes, so if you have a lot of users, you end up having a lot of contention.  You should consider migrating to another DBMS in order to satisfy your scaling needs.