# Avoid duplicate entry with has_many through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have been using this nested attributes with has_many :through

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checks_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :checks_tags

  attr_accessible :tags_attributes, :checks_tags_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :checks_tags
end 

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checks_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :checks, through: :checks_tags  
end

class CheckTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :check
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

so here the issue is when i create with this hash

```
"tags_attributes"=>[{"id"=>"", "name"=>"test12", "company_id"=>"1"}, {"id"=>"", "name"=>"test12", "company_id"=>"1"}]
```

actually here have two tags with same name, so its creating **Tag** twice and  after putting twice on **CheckTag**, so is there any way to avoid this creation as twice in Tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it forbidden in the database, you could create a unique index on the combination of the two columns on the `check_tag` table.  If you want to handle it in rails, you can do it with a before_save callback on the `Check` model (if that's the only way you create these), but that may make you vulnerable to a race condition.

See this answer:
[Index on multiple columns in RoR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169996/index-on-multiple-columns-in-ror)