# How to index already created data in rails?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to index already created columns with over 5 million data in my table. My question is if I add index with the migration will the already created data be indexed as well ? Or do I need to re-index the created data if so how ?

This is my migration

```
add_index :data_prods, :date_field
add_index :data_prods, :entity_id
```

Thank you.

**Edit**
I am using PostgreSQL dbms.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Index belongs to table, not to rows on table. Create your index and be happy.

Comment: So this will make the queries faster right? I am having a loading issue because of this much data.

Answer (score 1):

The process of adding an index re-indexes the entire tables contents. A table with 5 million rows may take some time, I suggest testing in a staging environment (with a similar amount of data) to see how long this migration will take, as well as impact to the application.

Re: your comment about improving query times

Indexes will make queries faster, where the indexed columns are commonly referenced in "where" clauses. In your case, any query where you filter by `date_field` OR `entity_id` will be faster, but other queries will not be improved. It should be noted that each query will only use 1 index, if the majority of your queries use both `date_field` AND `entity_id` at the same time to filter data, you might be better off using a composite index. Id check out this post for further reading on composite indexes. 
[Index on multiple columns in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169996/index-on-multiple-columns-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Could always use `connection.execute` to create indexes concurrently to help with no down time. Although that would make the creation of the index take longer.

Comment: @gdxn96 So composite indexing maybe better for me because I am using that combination in most of my queries.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Can you explain a bit on how to use the connetion.execute with no downtime.

Comment: @Amal , with `connection.execute` you can run raw SQL commands. So in your index you can do something like `create index concurrently idx_index_name on table_name using btree (column1)` Using the concurrent flag for creating an index will prevent a table lock. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html