# SQL pagination when ordering by modified date

Tags: sql, pagination

I have a bunch of records that I want to paginate by reverse modified date. From what I can tell, using a simple query pulls the same sub-set of records and then sorts only those by date.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE status='1' ORDER BY modified_date DESC LIMIT start,count
```

Would an index help me? Or am I going to have to figure out some way to code this perhaps adding a column that somehow keeps track of modified_date in reverse order?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful information. I believe the problem is that the DB stops searching after it finds the first 10 records specified by the WHERE clause and then only sorts those by date. What I want is to find the 10 most recently modified records from the entire DB. But it's looking like this might require more complicated programming.

Comment: What DB engine you are using?

Answer (score 1):

An index on (status, modified_date) might help. See [indexes dos and donts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes).

Answer (score 1):

This query looks good for me. It does the following:

1. Find records with `status = 1`
2. Order them by `modified_date DESC`
3. Return `count` records starting from `start`

So if you need to show first page, you should set `start=0`. For second page it'll be `start=count`, for third `start=2*count` and so on.

Or do you have performance problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column that holds a `TIMESTAMP` then set the auto-update property on it, so that it is properly updated. Finally, create an index for this column. Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM items 
WHERE status='1' 
ORDER BY 'timestamp' DESC 
LIMIT start,count
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a hack and I haven't tried it because I can't reproduce your problem and may not perform well but this may work for you

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   items 
        WHERE  status = '1' 
        ORDER  BY modified_date desc ) t
LIMIT  START, COUNT
```