# Postgres - Slow simple join with where-clause

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization, join

I am having some trouble optimizing a query, and was hoping that someone here might be able to provide a few pointers.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "blog_cached_posts" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('blog_cached_posts_id_seq'::regclass),
    "title" varchar(255),
    "content" text,
    "content_encoded" text,
    "published_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "written_by" varchar(255),
    "link" varchar(255),
    "blog_id" int4,
    "guid" varchar(255),
    "created_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "is_highlighted_post" bool DEFAULT false
)
```

With an index on blog_cached_posts.blog_id

```
CREATE TABLE "blogs" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('blogs_id_seq'::regclass),
    "site_id" int4,
    "image_id" int4,
    "name" varchar(255),
    "description" text,
    "url" varchar(255),
    "rss_feed_url" varchar(255),
    "active" bool DEFAULT true,
    "created_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "date_highlighted" date,
    "highlighted_category_feed_url" varchar(255),
    "position" int4
)
```

With an index on blogs.site_id

This is the query:

```
SELECT "blog_cached_posts".*
FROM "blog_cached_posts"
join blogs on blogs.id = blog_cached_posts.blog_id
WHERE ((published_at IS NOT NULL) AND (blogs.site_id = 80))
ORDER BY published_at desc
LIMIT 5
```

Here is an EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Limit  (cost=9499.16..9499.17 rows=5 width=1853) (actual time=118.538..118.539 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=9499.16..9626.31 rows=50861 width=1853) (actual time=118.536..118.537 rows=5 loops=1)
        Sort Key: blog_cached_posts.published_at
        Sort Method:  top-N heapsort  Memory: 33kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=16.25..8654.38 rows=50861 width=1853) (actual time=0.186..82.910 rows=48462 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (blog_cached_posts.blog_id = blogs.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on blog_cached_posts  (cost=0.00..7930.94 rows=52954 width=1853) (actual time=0.042..56.635 rows=52950 loops=1)
                    Filter: (published_at IS NOT NULL)
              ->  Hash  (cost=13.21..13.21 rows=243 width=4) (actual time=0.135..0.135 rows=243 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on blogs  (cost=0.00..13.21 rows=243 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.089 rows=243 loops=1)
                          Filter: (site_id = 80)
Total runtime: 118.591 ms
```

Is there any way to optimize this beyond the ~120ms it is currently taking?

**EDIT**

Here is what I ended up doing. (After reading the comment by @ypercube)

I added an index to blog_cached_posts:

```
CREATE INDEX \"blog_cached_posts_published_at\" ON \"public\".\"blog_cached_posts\" USING btree(published_at DESC NULLS LAST);
COMMENT ON INDEX \"public\".\"blog_cached_posts_published_at\" IS NULL;
```

And I changed the select to the following:

```
SELECT "blog_cached_posts".*
FROM "blog_cached_posts"
join blogs on blogs.id = blog_cached_posts.blog_id
WHERE published_at is not null and blogs.site_id = 80
ORDER BY published_at desc nulls last
LIMIT 5
```

This brought the execution time down to ~3ms.

Here is the new execution plan:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..3.85 rows=5 width=1849) (actual time=0.027..0.047 rows=5 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..39190.01 rows=50872 width=1849) (actual time=0.026..0.046 rows=5 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using blog_cached_posts_published_at on blog_cached_posts  (cost=0.00..24175.16 rows=52965 width=1849) (actual time=0.017..0.023 rows=5 loops=1)
              Filter: (published_at IS NOT NULL)
        ->  Index Scan using blogs_pkey on blogs  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=5)
              Index Cond: (blogs.id = blog_cached_posts.blog_id)
              Filter: (blogs.site_id = 80)
Total runtime: 0.086 ms
```

Comment: Did you try changing your index on `blog_cached_posts` from just the column `blog_id` to the columns `blog_id, published_at`?

Comment: I would also try adding a simple index on `published_at`

Comment: @Thomas - did u try my solution? If so, please post results. thx.

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to revisit the problem yet. Will test your suggestions today :)

Comment: @ypercube - Your suggestion worked. Adding a simple index for published_at desc nulls last, brought the execution-time down to ~3ms. - You should add an answer with the solution :)

Comment: @Thomas: are you sure this was the solution and not that the query were cached? Have you tried with `LIMIT 50` or `LIMIT 200` ? Is it also faster?

Comment: Oh, I see the different execution plan, OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, I would first try adding a simple index on `published_at`. It seems that if there wasn't the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 5` clauses, the query would be quite efficient and all other needed indexes existed.

Therefore, adding an index on the field that is used for the final sorting is usually quite efficient.

As Dems explained in his answer:

> Because the index ( `blog_id, published_at` ) is in a state that is good for the join, it turns out to be **less good for the sort**. On those grounds, you might see value in two indexes instead of one (on **blog_id** and **published_at** separately.)

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is you cannot realistically use an index to pull the needed 5 posts outright. Hop over to [index dos and donts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes/6098727#6098727) for a moment.

`(blog_id, published_at)` (suggested in comments) would arguably help if were querying for a specific blog, but your most selective constraint in that query is the one on the site_id -- i.e. on a separate table altogether.

```
Seq Scan on blogs  (cost=0.00..13.21 rows=243 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.089 rows=243 loops=1)
  Filter: (site_id = 80)
```

The above means that either you've no index on site_id, or that this particular site_id is all over the place and Postgres goes through the whole table since it'll need to open it regardless.

This then leads to multiple blog ids, and these are used to retrieve all of the relevant posts using a hash join. But since multiple blogs are involved, the best PG can do is to grab all applicable posts and subsequently top-n sort them.

Even if you were to change it so that you pass the blog ids directly in an `IN()` clause, an index on `(blog_id, published_at)` would not yield the needed rows in order. So it would still grab all posts for all of the applicable blogs, and top-n sort the mess.

One way to work around the problem would be to change your schema slightly:

```
CREATE TABLE "blog_cached_posts" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('blog_cached_posts_id_seq'::regclass),
    ...
    "published_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "site_id" int4,
    "blog_id" int4,
    ...
)
```

Note the extra site_id. This allows to subsequently create an index on `(site_id, published_at desc nulls last)` and rewrite your query like:

```
SELECT "blog_cached_posts".*
FROM "blog_cached_posts"
WHERE site_id = 80
ORDER BY published_at desc nulls last
LIMIT 5
```

---

An alternative approach, per comments, is to maintain a `latest_site_posts` table using triggers. You'll end up with something similar to the above suggestion, but with a smaller table (i.e. less duplication of the site_id).

Comment: I disagree.  Although it is likely correct that the most selective predicate is on `site_id`, the alteration of the index in include `published_at` should indeed make a potentially massive difference.  This would be because following the Filter by site_id, the join can hen be accomplished by an index look-up, rather than a sequential scan.

Comment: Indeed. But if his blogs contain 100k posts each, an index `(blog_id, published_at)` would result in retrieving `100k * number of blog` rows in the wrong order, which then need to be top-n sorted. By contrast, adding the extra site_id field as I suggest will allow the planner to grab the top-5 rows directly.

Comment: Actually, the LIMIT 5 ensures that only 5 posts are required for each blog_id.  Your suggestion does certainly guarantee the fasted possible solution to the query, but I would be apprehensive of such denormalisation unless it can be shown to be absolutely required.  Following this pattern of de-normalisation and indexing for all queries could lead to a very bloated schema indeed.  So I don't disagree with your assertions, only that I'd approach it as an if-needs-must option, rather than a preference.

Comment: "Actually, the LIMIT 5 ensures that only 5 posts are required for each blog_id." Actually... look at the explain/analyze. It's top-5 sorting 50861 posts pulled from 243 blogs. PG is fetching each every last applicable post before top-n sorting. And agreed, denormalization usually is bad. But this is one of those cases where it will actually make sense. (On a separate note, another option for him would be to maintain a "latest_posts" table using triggers.)

Comment: Only because at present the data is completely unordered (with respect to `published_at`).  With the suggested index you would effectively have several ordered lists (one for each blog_id).  The top 5 of each of these ordered lists can then be selected for a merge sort, yielding the final 5 required.  The 6th entry in any of the ordered lists is guaranteed to never be needed.  Indeed this is `5 * blog_count` rather than just `5`, but not the `n * blog_count` you may fear.

Comment: Post your 'latest posts' option as an answer, it's certainly viable :)

Comment: I wish you were correct, but I've never seen the Postgres planner behave as you suggest... 9.1 might change this: they added an optimization for partitioned tables so that fetching a max() no longer requires an index scan irrespective of indexes. But I'm suspicious it also applies to this particular use-case.

Comment: +1 just because of the weight of information, explanation and opinion this answer now provides to the OP.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, s/requires an index scan/requires a seq scan/ in my previous comment. ([Details here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2011-06/msg00139.php)) :-P

Comment: I like the idea, and it certainly makes sense. - Unfortunately I'm dealing with some legacy applications, so changing the schema is a bigger procedure than you might think :)

Comment: @Thomas: in that case, consider caching the results of your current query in memcached for a couple of minutes or hours.

Comment: @Denis - I already am. The data is used in a heavily cached Rails app, but I wanted to see if I could bring down the execution time for when the cache is expired :)

Comment: Well, in that case I'm afraid you're going to need to either change the existing table, or add a new one. :-)

Comment: @Denis - Take a look at my edit in the question-text - I found another solution.

Comment: Duh, you had no index on that to start with? :-D

Comment: @Denis, no - I was always under the impression that you shouldn't index date-columns because their rows are most likely all different. Well, you learn something new everyday, they say :)

Comment: +1 for the thorough and  detailed answer (and realizing that @Denis was under the impression that an index on `published_at` already existed but had not improved peeformance).

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on Denis' answer, and Thomas Mueller's comment...

An index on `blog_cached_posts` is needed to avoid a sequential scan of that table.  By making the the index cover `blog_id, published_at`, the query can follow logic similar to the following...
1. Filter the blogs table for the site_id (80)
2. For each record in there, join to blog_cached_posts
3. Use the blog_id, published_at index to identify the records needed
4. Possible merge that index on itself to allow a fast sort

Because the index is in a state that is good for the join, it turns out to be less good for the sort.  On those grounds, you might see value in two indexes instead of one (on blog_id and published_at separately.)

**EDIT**

In a comment on Denis' answer you say that adding a column could prove problematic due to legacy apps.  I can think of a couple of tips that may help there...

Try creating a new table with the fields you need, and replacing the original table with a view on to the new table.  The new table can have, for example, default values in the additional columns.

Or create a mapping table with the fiels you need to relate together for your query.  This mapping table can then be maintained via a trigger.

Comment: This didn't change the execution time

Comment: Did the EXPLAIN PLAN show use of the new index?  Or have you tried applying two indexes instead of one?  If nothing else works, it seems your're stuck with altering the schema.  See my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Because your best search predicate is site_id, switch your table select order around to select from `blogs` first, so it jumps straight in via the index. Also, put the `published_at not null` into the join so rows are cut off asap, like this:

```
SELECT blog_cached_posts.*
FROM blogs
join blog_cached_posts on blogs.id = blog_cached_posts.blog_id AND published_at IS NOT NULL
WHERE blogs.site_id = 80
ORDER BY published_at desc
LIMIT 5
```

Note that this solution does not require any new indexes, nor would it benefit from them.

Please let us know how this query performs in comparison

Comment: That suggestion will be strictly equivalent from Postgres' standpoint. His real issue is that he has no credible index to use to take advantage of the `limit 5` part of his statement.

Comment: Indeed, this mild reformulation of the SQL yields no alteration to the algorithmic expression.  Basically, when forming the plan, postgres would already 'see' what you're saying.

Comment: @Dems in my experience, I have not found that it figures that out. I have got fantastic improvements in query speed doing this. Let's see if he posts a change in speed with this approach

Comment: No changes in execution time for this method

Answer (score -1):

> - use LIMIT ['it fetch limited data from table']
> - Insded of blog_cached_posts.* use Required data only e.i
>     blog_cached_posts.name,blog_cached_posts.email
> - Avoid Unwanted "" quotes in select statement
>          SELECT `blog_cached_posts`.* FROM `blog_cached_posts`

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the OPs principle question : how to improve the query cost and so obtain faster execution.