# MySQL multiple indexes containing 1 col each? Or 1 index containing multiple cols?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

In MySQl InnoDB, does it matter how many columns are in a btree index?

For example:

```
Key1 contains cols (col1, col2, col3)
```

Or

```
Key1 contains col1
Key2 contains col2
Key3 contains col3
```

Does this matter? Thanks!

Comment: "Does this matter?" is a really poor question.  Yes, it "matters" in a lot of ways. There are trade offs for everything.  Please be more specific

Comment: What are the trade offs? I will be querying the columns both together and seperatly. Lots of selects, lots of inserts. Over 11M rows.

Comment: I'd say go for the design that makes more sense, data wise. For example, if there are always 3 columns, why not fetch them at once? Probably better with one row. If the number of columns varies, why store a lot of empty columns? Probably better with a row per column. I doubt either will be do-or-die performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it matters.

Larger indexes are, well... larger. :-) You know, more disk space, slower to read/update, etc.

In fact, when they're too large, they occasionally get ignored by the planner if a smaller, alternative index can do the trick.

Comment: So its better to create them seperately?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, on your db engine, etc.. Sometimes it's useful to have two or more columns in an index, and sometimes not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes/6098727#6098727

Answer (score 0):

An index on `(col1, col2, col3)` can be used for:

```
where col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 and col3 = 3
where col1 = 1 and col3 = 3
where col1 = 1
```

But not for:

```
where col2 = 2 and col3 = 3
where col3 = 3
```

To search quicky for a value of `col2`, you need an index that starts with `col2.`  Like `(col2)` but also `(col2, col3, col1)`.

So if you'd like to search for `col2` or `col3` independently from `col1`, three indexes are the much superior option.

Comment: Why would an index on col1, col2, and col3 work on col1 independently but NOT work on col2 and col3 independently? Does the order matter?

Comment: An index is like a paper phone book.  You can look people up by last name.  You can't look them up by first name.  In order to look them up by first name, a second phone book sorted by first name would be required.

Comment: @user1797484 Yes, multi column indexes have an order dependency, an index on (col1,col2) will not work on col2 only.